# How do I change the text color of the button returned by displayModeButtonItem in iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

In iOS8 I am using a splitViewController to present my data. I have a custom color for the navigation bar (light blue) and I set the color for the title to white. I would like to change the color of the text in the displayModeButtonItem to white as well, but no matter what I do, it stays the default blue when displayed on the iPhone. When displayed on the iPad it is white.

I have tried

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self.splitViewController displayModeButtonItem];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

but that does nothing. It seems that since this button is handled automatically by iOS, nothing I do can change it. Is there somewhere that I can intercept this button and set its color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky to find. In Interface Builder, you need to:

1. Find the Navigation controller for the Master View Controller.
2. Select the Navigation Bar
3. Change the Tint

[image: Visual Guide to changing return button tint]

Comment: That worked! If you push additional view controllers onto the detail nav controllers you may want to set its tint too.

Answer (score 1):

Objective c

In SceneDelegate.m

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {


UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
splitViewController.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the accepted answer, because you don't have a Navigation Controller in your Master View (as I didn't have), you can try the following:

```m
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

If you put this in the App Delegate it will make every UIBarButtonItem white (including the displayModeButtonItem), but you could target it more specific to the SplitViewController's displayModeButtonItem.